# We chose the golden ones and we smash them

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Those who are not generals
>   We chose the golden ones and we smash them,
>   and with the heart of some canes,
>   they are matched then.
>   We add salt to the wounds
>   of this refined group
>   And, this is crucial,
>   we make some fun guys join the troop.
>   After getting together a drink,
>   it's time to meet our needs though, don't you think?
>   So we turn up the heat,
>   then make the group pass the test,
>   and if they arise as one, soft and sweet,
>   it will, for sure, be the best!

What am I?

Comment: It sounds like __Candy Crush!__ :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it

> Bread?

Those who are not generals
We chose the golden ones and we smash them,

> Wheat kernels (colonels - not generals), milled to flour

and with the heart of some canes,
they are matched then.

> Sugar (from sugar **canes**) is added...

We add salt to the wounds
 of this refined group

> ...plus salt.

And, this is crucial,
we make some fun guys join the troop.
After getting together a drink,
it's time to meet our needs though, don't you think?

> This bit's about yeast- a fungus (fun guys) that is used in the production of bread. Plus, water is added (getting a drink): we obtain a knead dough (needs though)!

So we turn up the heat,
 then make the group pass the test,
 and if they arise as one, soft and sweet,
 it will, for sure, be the best!

> Bread rises in the oven, and we have 'the best thing since sliced bread'

Comment: isn't salt just another ingredient to make one?

Comment: Bread (or rather a recipe for bread) is the right answer. There are some wordplays within the riddle that point toward this answer, can you find them :)?

Comment: "refined" and "needs"? Not sure about the generals reference - maybe hinting to "colonels", specifically cornbread? That would work well with golden, too..